# Align multiple SKLabelNodes by Baseline

Tags: ios, fonts, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I have a collection of `SKLabelNodes`. Each node represents a letter of a word. Each node is the child of an `SKSpriteNode`. The `spriteNode`has an explicit hight set on it (the hight returned by `[text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : font}];`), and has the same width as the `labelNode`.

The `labelNode` is then centred inside the `spriteNode`, and has `verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBaseline`. At a later stage, I will need to set a background image on each letter (which will be done using the `spriteNode`). For testing purposes, I am using a solid colour, making the problem apparent:

[image]

As you can see, the lower part of the letter 'y' is showing bellow the container `spriteNode`. The same thing happens with 'g's and other letters. I should also explain that each `letterNode` (that is, the `spriteNode` and child `labelNode`) is centred vertically, and spaced out horizontally, inside another `SKSpriteNode`, used to contain all the letters for a word.

Code that creates the `letterNode`:

```
SKLabelNode *labelNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText:text];
labelNode.fontName = font.fontName;
labelNode.fontSize = font.pointSize;
labelNode.fontColor = colour;
labelNode.position = CGPointMake(0, -floor(height/2));
// height is the same explicit height used to create the spriteNode.

SNLetterNode *letter = [SNLetterNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] size:CGSizeMake(labelNode.frame.size.width, height)];
letter.letter = text;
letter.labelNode = labelNode;
letter.size = CGSizeMake(self.labelNode.frame.size.width, height);
```

The `SKSpriteNode` that contains all the letters for a word is created like so:

```
CGSize fullWordSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : font}];

SNWordNode *word = [SNWordNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:fullWordSize];
word.letterNodes = letterNodes;
word.text = text;
```

I believe the problem is being caused by the way I am positioning and/or sizing the `label` and `spriteNodes`. I have tried using different `verticalAlignmentModes`, and repositioning the labels based on that, all to no avail. If I knew of a way to align the nodes based on the baseline of the text, that would be a start.

What I would like to happen, is for the grey background to extend down, covering the lower part of the 'y', and for that to happen on **all** `letterNodes` (regardless of whether they require it, like the 'y'). And for the text to still be aligned by baseline.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out, the part of the (in my example) 'y' that was appearing bellow the border is called a "descender", according to Apple's docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/TypoFeatures/TextSystemFeatures.html).

`UIFont` has a property on it, called `descender`, and it gives you the highest value the descent can be. I used that to increase the size of the `SKSpriteNode` containing the `SKLabelNode`, and properly centre the label.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to note I posted my approach (for a similar issue) here. My solution is based on your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682287/250164