# Vertical alignment of iAP currency labels

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

I'm having some issues with the vertical alignment of different currencies for some in app purchases. My purchase labels all align perfectly in dollar figures, but for larger Japanese Yen figures they appear to be pushed up. The only difference appears to be the comma, but I'm unsure how to resolve this.

I'm aligning all my labels using

```
coinLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
```

Thank you in advance!

**US Example:**
[image: US Example]
**Yen Example:**
[image: Yen Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.baseline`, not `.center` as the , descends below the baseline.  Using `.center` centers the entire text frame around the origin.  Using `.baseline` places the baseline of the text at the origin and ensures that the descender does not impact the placement of the text in the node.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sending me on the right path. I was able to combine your answer with another to get it working

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850592/spritekit-is-there-a-way-to-centre-a-sklabelnode-according-to-its-baseline